# Get all the elements inside a div which are tabable in dom tree order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement to handle all the elements inside a DIV. Elements must be tabbable. i am trying like this

```
jQuery("#container a,:input:not(:hidden)")
```

But it is fetching me all the input elemnts on the page. how to get the `elements(a,:input:not(:hidden))` inside this div. TIA

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing :

```
jQuery("#container a,:input:not(:hidden)")
        ^ (1)        ^ (2)
```

1. There you're searching in the container, the a element.
2. You're searching not hidden :input (pseudo-classes input does exists ?) in the whole page !

Try this one :

```
jQuery("#container a, #container input:not(:hidden)")
```

Comment: Add an explanation with the answer